# Django - model.objects.all.exists() vs model.objects.exists()

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views

Which one would be the standardised way to check if any record exists in a table? We can use either `model.objects.all().exists()` or `model.objects.exists()`. But which one should be the standard practice?

Comment: `model.objects.all.exists()` will not work: it is `model.objects.all().exists()`, both will produce the same query, so both take the same amount of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would prefer `model.objects.exists()` because it's less code to write. As mentioned in comment - both produce the same query